# linked server to excel permissions

Tags: sql-server-2008

Ok, I give up, I have no clue and I desperately need help. Normally I loath excel for storing data but... what can you do?

**What I want to do:**

Allow user to get data from .xls file via stored procedure and linked server (using Microsoft.ACE.OLEDB.12.0)

**Tthe problem:**

User gets error:

```
OLE DB provider "Microsoft.ACE.OLEDB.12.0" for linked server "LS" returned message
  "The Microsoft Access database engine cannot open or write to the file ''.
  It is already opened exclusively by another user,
    or you need permission to view and write its data.".
Msg 7303, Level 16, State 1, Line 1
Cannot initialize the data source object of OLE DB provider
  "Microsoft.ACE.OLEDB.12.0" for linked server "LS".
```

Administrator runs `select * from LS...[data$]` and gets full rowset

**What I did:**

I gave the user permissions to temp in SQL service account directory.
User has full control over the file to which linked server is connected.

**What I am sure of:**

File is NOT opened by another user.

Comment: Look at the linked server options, there are security options. Play with this setting http://i.stack.imgur.com/zOrJV.png

Comment: thanks for answer. linked server security settings are fine, if they were not - admin would not be able to query it (i've seen a whole load of "unspecified errors")

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**resolved**

There is custom *.mdw file for this provider (I found it somewhere in registry, HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE/Software/Microsoft)
It turned out user didn't have permissions to open this file.

Thx for all answers :)